# I Can't Use DISTINCT With SUM in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, distinct

I want to collect data from different tables in SQL with `SUM`. I want to multiply the `piece` and `price` of the product and add the `cargoprice` next to it, but I have to use one of these because `cargoprice` is on multiple lines. But I can not use `DISTINCT` as follows:

```
SELECT 
SUM((tbl_Product.price * piece) + DISTINCT(tbl_Cargo.cargoprice)) AS total 
FROM tbl_Order 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Product ON tbl_Product.productid = tbl_Order.productid 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Cargo on tbl_Cargo.cargoid = tbl_Order.cargoid 
WHERE userid = '1'
```

Comment: My guess is that you do not need SUM or DISTINCT clauses. To get a right answer for this question you would need to provide sample data from both tables and desired output.

Comment: share your schema and sample data and the results that you want to get

Answer (score 0):

You can use "group by" in your query. Sample codes are below;

```
select SUM(price*piece)+cargoPrice,cargoPrice from (
select 5 as price,2 as piece,1 as cargoPrice
union all
select 5 as price,2 as piece,1 as cargoPrice
union all
select 5 as price,2 as piece,2 as cargoPrice
union all
select 5 as price,3 as piece,2 as cargoPrice
union all
select 5 as price,4 as piece,3 as cargoPrice
)A
group by cargoPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

One cargo can contain several orders. So you may have orders #1 and #2 shipped with cargo #100 and orders #3 and #4 shipped with cargo #200. So you need the sum of two orders, but of only two cargos in this example.

To solve this, group your orders by cargo:

```
select sum(per_cargo.pricesum + tbl_cargo.cargoprice) as total
from
(
  select o.cargoid, sum(p.price * p.piece) as pricesum
  from tbl_order o
  join tbl_product p on p.productid = o.productid
  where o.userid = 1
  group by o.cargoid
) per_cargo
join tbl_cargo on tbl_cargo.cargoid = per_cargo.cargoid ;
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem with this code: `SELECT DISTINCT(tbl_Cargo.cargoprice) + SUM(tbl_Product.price * piece) AS total 
FROM tbl_Order 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Product ON tbl_Product.productid = tbl_Order.productid 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Cargo on tbl_Cargo.cargoid = tbl_Order.cargoid 
WHERE userid = '1' GROUP BY tbl_Cargo.cargoprice`

Comment: Are you sure this is SQL Server? Your query is invalid and should result in a syntax error. The only DBMS I know of that would let this slip (and return an undesired result instead) is MySQL. `DISTINCT` is not a function; it works on the whole line; the prarentheses in `SELECT DISTINCT(tbl_Cargo.cargoprice)` are superfluous hence. You select one row (because there is aggregation without a `GROUP BY` clause). `DISTINCT` reduces the one row to ..., well, one row :-)

Comment: **In MySQL:** To the sum of price x piece you add one cargoprice picked from any record arbitrarily chosen. **In SQL Server:** To the sum of price x piece you add one cargoprice, but he aggregation doesn't contain a single cargoprice and you get a syntax error message.

Comment: I forgot to add "GROUP BY tbl_Cargo.cargoprice" So yes, my code works for me.

Comment: Ah, so you want one result row per cargoprice. I.e. with three cargos of cargoprice 1000, 2000, and 1000, you want two result rows, one for 1000, one for 2000. This is new information. Still the `DISTINCT` is superfluous; you can remove it completely from the query.